# Constructor not called while Deserialising

Tags: java, serialization

I am not sure whether in other languages also this occurs or not. But I would really like to know the exact reason for why the constructor of the class is not called when we deserialize an object.

Comment: @KevinBowersox. I removed the JPA tag.

Comment: Because that's what it says in the Object Serialization Specification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor is meant to initialize an object's state. A deserialized object was already in an initialized state. The deserialization should only re-constitute that old state. Thus the constructor code is not executed anymore.

It would also makes no sense to execute the constructor code and then override the state by deserialization.

There is an internal class that allows this (create an instance without executing the conostructor code). That class is also used by mock frameworks like powermock.

The class I'm taking about is named `sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory`. This class has a method called `newConstructorForSerialization()`.

Frameworks like objenesis use them. Take a look at the [package summary](http://objenesis.googlecode.com/svn-history/r205/docs/apidocs/org/objenesis/instantiator/sun/package-summary.html). So if you want to use such functionality I would use objenesis.

Comment: This means that we can create objects with new operator without the constructor also? if we know that class

Comment: It is not so easy to just write "new ..." without executing the constructor code, but there is a class inside the jvm that can do this. I m searching for it and then I update my answer.

Comment: @KevinBowersox there is no real relationship to JPA. JPA also uses serialization and the question is about that.

Comment: @RenéLink or the OP could have just misplaced that tag

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk I agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is very simple why deserialization in Java does not use a constructor: the whole purpose of it was to get an object in the exactly same state as it was when serialized. Operations in the constructor might alter that state.

Answer (score 0):

Serialization is an extra linguistic way of creating an object. while Deserializing it just need to set the member variable values from the byte stream. so need of constructer call, because deserialization itself is constructing the object in place of constructer.

```
public class MyClass implements Serializable
{
private  final static long serialVersionUID = 130942892839284932L;   


    private transient String name;
    private transient int count;
    private String firstName;

    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream objectInputStream) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
        {
            System.out.println("readObject!!!!");
            objectInputStream.defaultReadObject();
            count = objectInputStream.readInt();
            name = (String)objectInputStream.readObject();
        }
}
```

Like here `readObject` is constructing the object from byte stream.